# Generate Panel of overlapping features and export them to csv with GIS and Python

Tags: pyqgis, spatial-query

Given is a dataset, split into 250 .gml files, containing multiple vector layers.

The features of interest are:

parcels as polygons (~250k total),

buildings as polygons (~350k total),

addresses as points (~250k total)

Note that attributes of the interesting features vary over files; buildings and addresses not necessarily have to appear in each file.

Assignment) Write a python script that gets all buildings and addresses that intersects with parcels and creates a new layer with joined attributes of parcels and intersected addresses/buildings) for export to csv.

---

Well, that's my homework.
I started by writing following code which isn't working (run on a single file):

```
for pc in parcels:
    bd_res = None
    ad_res = None
    for bd in buildings:
        if bd.geometry().within(pc.geometry()):
            bd_res = bd
            print 'Building: '+`bd_res['gml_id']`
    for ad in adresses:
        if ad.geometry().within(pc.geometry()):
            ad_res = ad
            print 'Adress: '+`ad_res['gml_id']
```

The Output is (no error messages):

```
Adress: u'DEHHALKAz00031c3'
```

It fails at the if-condition, where the method .within(pc.geometry()) only returns a single address and no buildings.

Furthermore I'm uncertain about assigning polygons to polygons and I'm a bit worried about the execution time, if there is a more efficient method, just mention.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format so I think you should focus on I) and remove II) and III).  What precisely "isn't working"?  What happens when you run the code snippet that you have presented here?

Comment: Hey PolyGeo, thanks for the informtion. I'll read the tour and then edit my question later :) The output of the script above (runned on a subsample) is only one gml_id of an adress ... if necessary I can post a screenshot of the objects in the map window ...

Comment: @Active Please [edit] your question to include any response to comments.  Comments are for potential answerers to request clarification and more information, your response should be as an edit to the question.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?